# Unable to form Pivot query for splited string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, pivot-table

I have two types of strings

1. Firstname Lastname.  ex: John Doe
2. Lastname, Firstname. ex: Doe, John

I need to split it into tables like

| FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- |
| John | Doe |

I am using this query

```
declare @query nvarchar(100) = 'Doe, John'

select FirstName, LastName
from
(
  select (select count(*) from dbo.SplitString(@query, ',') T1 where [Item]=T1.Item) value, Item
  from dbo.SplitString(@query, ',')
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for Item in (Firstname, LastName)
) piv;
```

But this is not working.

`SplitString()` return like this:

| Item |
| --- |
| John |
| Doe |

I am not that much expert in Pivot tables. Please someone help me figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: What about someone called `Martin Luther King` or `Andrew Lloyd Webber` (whos surnames are `King` and `Lloyd Webber` respectively)? How do you know what names are their surname and what are their forename? You *can't* assume that the *last* "name" is the Surname.

Comment: Related reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: We only have the formats I mentioned.

Comment: So you can't do it, and you have no idea if the value `Andrew Lloyd Webber` should be `Andrew`,`Lloyd Webber`, or `Andrew Lloyd`,`Webber`.

Comment: I will handle those cases if I can get a help for mentioned cases. My task was to only focus on above two cases. I asked client for middle name but he said we will consider middle name later. But I will fix it if you just help me for only first and last name.

Comment: There is no solution, not for the names that don't have commas (aren't in the format `Surnames, Forenames`) any way.